# How can I tell which of my pages are single-view pages?

Tags: php

I am trying to understand what the `is_singular()` function does. And I found this definition:

```
is_singular() tag enables you to target single-view pages, regular page pages, and attachment pages
```

But the problem is that I am not sure how to determine which are single-view pages, regular pages, and category pages.

What I really need to do is determine if a page is a category page.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

First off, take a look at [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) in general.

> I am trying to understand what the is_singular() function does.

Straight from the codex: "*This conditional tag checks if a singular post is being displayed, which is the case when one of the following returns true: `is_single()`, `is_page()` or `is_attachment()`.*"

> What I really need to do is determine if a page is a category page.

The conditional tag that applies here would be [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category), which returns `true`, if a category archive page is displayed.

> But the problem is that I am not sure how to determine which are single-view pages, regular pages, and category pages.

As you do not care about attachment pages, [`is_singular()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) obviously isn't for you.
Still something can be learned from its description - namely, the other two tags (the category one aside) needed to determine whether your condition is met:

[`is_single()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) and [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

Hence,

```
if ( is_single() || is_page() || is_category() ) {
    // do your thing
}
```

is what you want.

Should chaining of expressions in PHP be new to you, take a look at its [logical operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).